# Pandas import excel won't allow datetime format on time column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have been using pandas for importing excel files of data, and I'm having difficulty getting one particular file with respect to the time column.

One file I import has a date/time column.  This gets imported in pandas as datetime64[ns], and I can use the time for the x-axis in plotting.  I use the following code to pull the time out as a separate vector.

```py
dateandtime=df[df.columns[0]]
time=dateandtime.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

This works fine.

I have another file from another device that has two columns, one for date and one for time.  When this one gets imported, only the date column is formatted as datetime64[ns].  When I import this data, the structure looks like this:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3205 entries, 0 to 3204
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   Date            3205 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   Time            3205 non-null   object        
 2   E_VFD_HZ        3205 non-null   int64         
 3   Extraction_PSI  3205 non-null   float64       
 4   Kiln_hdr_PSI    3205 non-null   float64       
 5   Kiln_Stm_DegF   3205 non-null   float64       
 6   Kiln_Stm_DP     3205 non-null   float64       
 7   Kiln_Stm_lbshr  3205 non-null   float64       
 8   Main_Stm_DP     3205 non-null   float64       
 9   Main_Stm_lbshr  3205 non-null   int64         
 10  Main_Stm_PSI    3205 non-null   float64       
 11  O2_wet          3205 non-null   float64       
 12  W_VFD_HZ        3205 non-null   int64
```

I need to be able to use the Time vector for plotting, but also for comparing time stamps to other files.  I need it to be a datetime format.  I have tried numerous ways to convert this to a datetime format and it has not worked.  When I attempt it I get the error:

```
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime, at position 0
```

Here is the code for that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('23112900.xlsx')

df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

print(df.info())
```

I have run out of things to try, so I thought I would ask the group.

1. Is there a way to turn this time vector into a datetime object?
2. Can I merge the Date and Time columns into a single datetime object?

Thanks.  Also I would like to attach the excel file but I don't see an option for that, so I'll cut and paste a few rows.

Comment: Please format ('Code Sample' for code, 'Block Quote' for data) and add sample data to your question